# How to save file from POST request in flask to localy-running Minio server?

Tags: python, flask, minio

I'm trying to save file to bucket:

```
if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    try:
        minioClient.make_bucket("testbuck", location = "us-east-1")
    except BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou as err:
        pass
    except BucketAlreadyExists as err:
        pass
    except ResponseError as err:
        raise
    else:
        try:
            print(filename)
            minioClient.fput_object('testbuck', filename, image)
        except ResponseError as err:
            print(err)
```

But get errors:`Message: {0}'.format(error.message))
InvalidXMLError: InvalidXMLError: message: "Error" XML is not parsable. Message: syntax error: line 1, column 0`

I'm newby in backend and flask and can't figure out what I am doing wrong! Thank for you patience

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. It looks like there have been some changes in the indentation of your code during formatting.

Comment: @xg.plt.py sorry, I've fixed it, it's courtesy of stackowerflow  indentation ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

The pymino's **minioClient.fput_object()** method expects existing bucket name, object name to be kept and filepath of the file to be uploaded.

> Usage :
>   
>   **minioClient.fput_object( bucket_name, object_name, filepath)**

Add the following in the beginning Replace `image` with the filepath.

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/path/to/the/uploads'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER`
```

Add the following before making **fput_object** function:

```
filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
filepath = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
```

> Example:
>   
>   **minioClient.fput_object( "testbuck", filename, filepath)**